# Detecting if a job has been dispatched using dispatchNow

Tags: php, laravel, jobs

I have a job that under certain circumstances calls another job

```php
<?php namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Models\Account;

class EnqueueScheduledDownloads implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $account;

    public function __construct(Account $account)
    {
        $this->account = $account;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        foreach($this->account->pending_downloads as $file)
        {
            DownloadFile::dispatch($file);
        }
    }
}
```

While the download job is usually executed in a queue; there are times, for example during testing, where it would make my life much easier if the whole chain was processed synchronously in a blocking fashion. I would like to be able to do something like this:

```php
public function handle()
{
    foreach($this->account->pending_downloads as $file)
    {
        if($this->getDispatchMode() == 'sync') {
            DownloadFile::dispatchNow($file);
        } else {
            DownloadFile::dispatch($file);
        }

    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: `dispatchNow` should run the cron synchronously, and that should work just fine?

Comment: @Leo I'm not sure I understand what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of poking around I was able to answer my own question. Yes it is possible; if a job is dispatched via `dispatchNow()` the `job` property of the Queueable object will be null, whereas if it is dispatched on a connection using `dispatch()` it will be set to an implementation of Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\Job. So the handle method can be changed as such:

```php
public function handle()
{
    foreach($this->account->pending_downloads as $file)
    {
        if(is_null($this->job)) {
            DownloadFile::dispatchNow($file);
        } else {
            DownloadFile::dispatch($file);
        }
    }
}
```

And it will work as expected. I was able to find this solution by creating a new job:

```php
<?php namespace App\Jobs;

class TestJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        dump(get_object_vars($this));
    }
}
```

and dispatching it on various queue and connections as well as with `dispatchNow()` and observing the output. Furthermore it is possible to retreive the connection and queue the job was dispatched on from the `$this->job`:

```
public function handle()
{
    echo $this->job->getConnectionName();
    echo $this->job->getQueue();
}
```